# Sample Component with Content Versioning from Joomla Site not working correctly

Tags: version-control, joomla3.3

I was trying to restore a version of a content I am editing.

in my administrator/components/com_joomprosubs/tables/subscription.php

in the construct function I added this following line:

```
JObserverMapper::addObserverClassToClass('JTableObserverContenthistory',
'JoomprosubsTableSubscription', array('typeAlias' =>'com_joomprosubs.subscription'));
```

from what I have read in this link:

https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Content_History_in_your_Component

but when I try to restore a version, an error is displayed:

"Error restoring item version from history."

I have followed the procedures step by step from that link. The storing of content history works, the only problem is when I try to restore the older versions. I even downloaded the finished sample file on the link's above.

The error is being return due to the blank value of typeAlias. I don't know where I got it wrong. from the code that I added above, I have included the typeAlias with its corresponding value. The weird thing is, if my code above does not work, it would not been also able to store content history.

Has anybody tried adding versioning in their custom component in Joomla? Please leave your comments.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I temporarily overridden the loadHistory function from the Base Class.

from there, i passed the alias as 'com_joomprosubs.subscription'. The restoring of version history is now working.

Is there a disadvantage in my resolution?